# Google Spreadsheet AVERAGE formula ignores filter

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a simple column (A for eample) with numeric values.

```
A
1
2
5
7
```

On another cell I have a basic formula like this one below.

```
=AVERAGE(Data!A:A)
```

If I apply a filter on column A the average doesn't change and ignores the filter. I know that there's an expression that can receive one or more criteria as parameter (AVERAGEIFS) but I don't know how to get the current filter applied.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUBTOTAL(1,A:A)
```

but I prefer `filter` function:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(A:A,B:B="a"))
```

Comment: I am soooo stupid :) I actually used SUBTOTAL a couple of months ago but I completely forgot about it. Thanks!